# Quickest way to change a value against a lookup list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list.

```
ViewBag.Meters = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Meters");
```

And an `Id`

```
3
```

How do I get `Meters.Name` from `ViewBag.Meters`, where `Id = 3`

As simple as possible, so that my view code is neat.

(My view currently shows only foriegn keys (ids), rather than its actual name)

Comment: What data type is `db`?  Are you using EF/LINQ?  What data type is `ViewBag.Meters`?

Comment: At the moment my view is just using @Html.DisplayForModel(). No idea what its setting viewbag.meters to tbh as its dynamically setting it on the fly. db is `using WebMatrix.Data;` - `Database` Type

Comment: I origionally joined the tables to produce me names instead, but then come forms, I didnt have the Ids to send to the DB on insert.

Comment: Whats your model?  Is it IEnumerable<Meter> ?

Comment: @Maess There is no model for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to do what you were doing I would create a simple utils function such as

```
public static string GetMeterNameById(int MeterId)
{
    return db.FirstOrDefault<Meter>("WHERE Id = @0", MeterId).Name;
}
```

Then inside the view just place a using for the namespace of the Utils class and then call the function

```
Utils.GetMeterNameById(Model.Id)
```

I have an enourmous Utility class that provides all kinds of flexibility when needing to return data in a clean way. Hopefully this is as efficient as I believe it to be.

Without more specifics its hard for me to tell if that would suite your application, elaborate more and I'd be glad to help.

Comment: This is a good idea. I didnt realise you could have such methods in the controller. I had gone and created two methods/models, where one provides ids and one provides the names.

Comment: Yep yep, I generally create many different classes that allow me to interact with the database on the fly through a Utility function. I find it makes it easier to work with the code later in the future as well coupled with proper naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

```
((IEnumerable<Meter>)ViewBag.Meters).Where(meter => meter.Id == 3).First().Name
```

but I would NOT do that in the view. The code belongs in the ViewModel (which you should create)